# Best way to structure class/struct in c#

Tags: c#, class, networking, struct

I've been working with network protocol specification targeted for implementation in C language and defined respectively in C style like:

```
struct some_header {
  uint8_t version;
  uint8_t type;
  uint16_t length;
  uint32_t id; /
};

struct some_struct {
  struct some_header header;
  uint8_t field1; 
  uint8_t pad[3]; /* Pad to 32 bits */
  uint32_t field2;
};
```

There are around hundred structures like "some_struct" defined in the specification.

Now the goal is to replicate the definitions in C# and grow some functionallity around those structures.

What is the best primitive to use in C# to represent the structures like in example above, assuming that it will be nice to have them represented as an object?

1. Use unsafe clause to replicate C-like definition and then use class wrapper around every structure
2. Use StructLayout attribute to guide the layout inside the managed structure and use wrapper class for each such structure
3. Use full-fledged class and only go to wire representation with Memory or Network Streams

Any other ideas, except managed c++?

Secondly, obviously the task by itself is very labor intensive and error-prone in any case listed. Is there any automation to help converting C header into one of the solutions above? Could someone recommend one, please?

**UPD.**

Some drawings to describe the problem better.

(BoxA) --- wire protocol running over TCP/IP --- (BoxB)

Assume BoxA runs some code written in pure C, BoxB ought to run code written in C#.

And wire protocol represents this huge specification with 100+ structures to communicate BoxA and BoxB. It could have been much easier if protocol had been defined with Google Protocol Buffers or Apache Thrift, but unfortunately I'm dealing with standard defined as it is.

Comment: You may find this resource helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4xwz0t37.aspx

Comment: A byte in C# is an unsigned 8-bit value so that may serve your needs perfectly.

Comment: Apparently, I didn't make the problem clear. Indeed I'm aware how to convert the basic types like uint8_t into c# counterparts. The question though was about migrating the c-style structures into c# representation in the best possible way.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO it's better to manually convert them as follows:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
public struct Header
{
    public Byte version;
    public Byte type;
    public UInt16 length;
    public UInt32 id;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
public struct Struct
{
    public Header header;
    public Byte field1;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=3)]
    public Byte[] pad;
    public UInt32 field2;
}
```

You will maybe have to use them in together with native functions in the future... so it' better to keep them as structures and use them directly in your .NET code. They will be very useful if you have to pass them as parameters for native methods or to convert result IntPtrs back to them ([Marshal.PtrToStructure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ca6d5z7.aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any automation to help converting C header into one of the solutions above?

Use C preprocessor to get one big file, then use script to cut struct definitions, then apply search & replace to convert types and add attributes.

Answer (score 0):

My inclination would be to use a type that encapsulates a byte array reference and an index, and then have methods to read or write the next byte/word/longword/whatever from it.  The code to convert from a byte stream to a structure type would then look something like:

```
myReader = new ByteArrayReader(myArr);
myHead.version = myReader.getByte();
myHead.type; = myReader.getByte();
myHead.length = myReader.getUInt16();
myHead.id = myReader.getUInt32();
```

In this case, I'm assuming `myHead` would be a transparent structure with the above-named public fields.  I wouldn't recommend making the header type a class unless instances are actually going to "do" something.  Making the reader type a structure might improve performance, but could in some cases cause surprising semantics.  The closest equivalent in the Framework is `List<T>.Enumerator`, which is a struct for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the automation question I've just found excellent tool producing PInvoke style code from c-header

http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/releases/view/14120#ReviewsAnchor

specifically one would need use following tool at command line

sigimp /lang:cs "path-to-c-header"

Below the example of produced code:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct some_header {

/// uint8_t->unsigned char
public byte version;

/// uint8_t->unsigned char
public byte type;

/// uint16_t->unsigned int
public uint length;

/// uint32_t->unsigned int
public uint id;
}

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Ansi)]
public some_struct {


public some_header header;

/// uint64_t->unsigned int
public uint xxx;

/// uint32_t->unsigned int
public uint xxx2;

/// uint8_t->unsigned char
public byte xxx3;

/// uint8_t->unsigned char
public byte xxx4;

/// uint8_t[2]
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=2)]
public string pad;

/// uint32_t->unsigned int
public uint xxx5;

/// uint32_t->unsigned int
public uint xxx6;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

While C# has `Struct`, your best bet is to use `Class`. You can use classes as data container, see anemic domain modal, or you can have implementation, such as validation, and business logic within. See: domain driven.

While working on your domain model, ensure to embrace, [SOLID principles](http://www.firatatagun.com/solid-principles/).

Also, based on your domain model, certainly you can utilize abstraction, inheritance and so forth.

oh. keep it simple and intuitive.

Comment: -1 I don't see how this advice relates to the question at all?

Comment: I think when the code is deseralising from the network, value types would be preferable.

Comment: @PeterWishart - Out of curiosity, why are value types preferable?

Comment: @JustinMorgan: When using reference types, one must either (1) construct a new immutable object instance for each thing which is read; since one will likely be reading a lot of things, that can get expensive; (2) return a new mutable object instance, with unclear semantics about what it would mean for the recipient to modify it, or (3) require that the recipient of the data supply a mutable object instance into which the data will be placed.  Mid-sized structs will generally be more efficient than immutable objects unless the average object would have 3 or more refs to it.

Comment: @JustinMorgan I'm assuming the OP is going to use e.g. Marshal.PtrToStructure to manually deserialise these objects from a network buffer to managed data first, so he'd want 'public Header header' to not be a reference.